# numpy arrays will not concontenate

Tags: python, numpy

I have three arrays a, b, c.

The are the shapes (1496,) (1496,) (1496, 1852). I want to join them into a single array or dataframe.

The first two arrays are single column vector, where the other has several columns. All three have 1496 rows.

My logic is to join into a single array by df=np.concontenate((a,b,c))

But the error says dimensions must be the same size.

I also tried np.hstack()

Thanks

MPG

Comment: What do you want to happen to the multiple columns in that array?  Do you want them to be flattened/unraveled into one long 1D array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `np.hstack((a.reshape(1496, 1), b.reshape(1496, 1), c))`. To be more general, it is `np.hstack((a.reshape(a.size, 1), b.reshape(b.size, 1), c))`

Comment: would have never thought of that on my own- but worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
np.hstack((np.transpose((a,b)),c))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other excellent answers, I propose a little experiment

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.random.random((3))

In [3]: b = np.random.random((3,5))

In [4]: print a; print b
[ 0.79029173  0.94967409  0.92041   ]
[[ 0.06362335  0.89737425  0.68929303  0.54940466  0.18666093]
 [ 0.63062331  0.79704639  0.6342981   0.32551241  0.92139038]
 [ 0.0389163   0.79205812  0.09504207  0.19657025  0.64401272]]

In [5]:
```